# Pivot dataframe to automatically make columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, multiple-columns

I have a data frame like this

```
Date Lag
d1    20
d1    30
d1    40
d2    10
d2    50
```

and want to convert to something like this

```
Date  <column names>
d1    20 30 40
d2    10 50 None
```

the columns can be named anything. any way to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Learnt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create new column names by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to new column and then use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df)
  Date  Lag
0   d1   20
1   d1   30
2   d1   40
3   d2   10
4   d2   50

df['g'] = df.groupby('Date')['Lag'].cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='g', values='Lag')
print (df)
g        0     1     2
Date                  
d1    20.0  30.0  40.0
d2    10.0  50.0   NaN
```

Also you can change column names:

```
df['g'] = 'Col' + df.groupby('Date')['Lag'].cumcount().astype(str)
print (df)
  Date  Lag     g
0   d1   20  Col0
1   d1   30  Col1
2   d1   40  Col2
3   d2   10  Col0
4   d2   50  Col1

df = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='g', values='Lag')
print (df)
g     Col0  Col1  Col2
Date                  
d1    20.0  30.0  40.0
d2    10.0  50.0   NaN
```